# Google Chart Dispose of Control

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I was wondering if there is a way to dispose of a control in Google Charts? I think this will solve my problem.

So if you have a control for a table defined initially like so...

```
stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                'containerId': 'control1',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnLabel': 'ColumnNameToFilterOn'
                }
            });
```

If later on you have some checkboxes to show/hide columns. Using `view.setColumns(state)` where `state` is an array of the columns to display. The issue is after hiding the column this way you end up with two errors and the column not actually becoming hidden.

```
One or more participants failed to draw()
Invalid column label: Issue Title
```

`view.setColumns(state)` works fine for any column without a controlType defined for it.

Comment: are you using a dashboard? how do you redraw the table after hiding columns?

Comment: Instead of trying to have the `view.setColumns(state)` I changed it to show/hide columns with jQuery instead. Error goes away and saves me from re-rendering the dashboard. After doing quite a bit of research it appears that once a bind (`dashboard.bind(stringFilter, table);`) is called you need to redraw that dashboard.